# Root cannot be null

Tags: javafx

I am trying to open a new window. Specifying the controller programmatically.

```
OverviewController overviewController = new OverviewController();

final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("overview.fxml"));
loader.setController(overviewController);

Parent root = loader.getRoot(); // Gives me a "Root cannot be null" error...

Stage stage = new Stage();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);

stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.show();
```

So it goes wrong after loading the root.

The following code does work, but i want to specify my own controller in the code.

```
Parent root = null;

try {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("overview.fxml"));

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `getRoot()` is returning null is that you haven't actually loaded the FXML file. You need:

```
loader.load();
Parent root = loader.getRoot();
```

or, more simply,

```
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `loader.setRoot()` in case you use a dynamic root, `<fx:root type="...">` …
And as @James_D pointed out, you have not loaded the fxml file…

Comment: You only need to call `setRoot()` if you use a "dynamic root"; i.e. you use `<fx:root type="...">` as the root element in the FXML. There's no suggestion at all in the question that the OP is doing that (and if he were, the second code block wouldn't work).